# NooB Alert NodeJs and Slack Bot build. Need Advice

Tags: node.js, api, bots, slack

Prewarning: I am a noob with development, I started doing web design when I retired from the Marines about 3 years ago. I specialized in Intelligence and Tactics, so not a computer user during that career. Fast forward to Today:

I work as an Exchange admin and migration specialist with GoDaddy, I have been through several Webdesign courses and learned a decent foundation of html/css/php however JavaScript, Nodejs, Java, Python, C++, and C# are all still things I am working on.

My issue: My lead wants to have a bot built that essentially posts messages in the #general group (I learned how to do this and actually setup a nodejs server within my test hosting server @ GD and have a Joke bot running in my slack WS). The tricky part that I have been scratching my brain on is how to use an web API that GD has to monitor our call que, hold times, and agents online. I need to figure out how to get the bot to post a message regarding certain triggers automatically(exp. Hold time exceeds 10mins). I can not figure out whether to use a webhook, eventListener, or a direct bot auth'd into the GD api like my joke bot that links to chuckNorris jokes.

I appreciate all the comments truly, I have thick skin and know that I am late to the game on development. I want to build this for the experience and to integrate with slack, my end goal would be more projects to eventually become a Dev within GD.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few thoughts that might help you.

Regarding these holdtimes, agents online, and call queues, think of these as events. Whenever these events occur, they should fire a payload (HTTP request) to your service that then posts messages to slack. I think you might need a slack bot token for this.

Many APIs have this functionality under webhooks. You provide them the URL to the endpoint your developing and theres usually a toggle to tell them that you want to start accepting events.

To get going on your service/bot, I'd recommend starting with learning about what these webhook event payloads will look like in terms of structure so that you can parse it.

If you have more detailed questions feel free to comment or message. Happy to help. I've written a slack bot or two.

Comment: I am trying to get access to the API built in order to see how the events are being run, I was thinking it would be a webhook so thank you for confirming that for me. 

One issue I will need to look into once I get an understanding of the webhook events, is how to get them through a local intranet. I know its possible since devs have an incident ticketing system for the whole company that posts updates of UI issues, server issues, Email issues, ect... as the "IRIS Bot"

Comment: Yeah,  you will need a publicly accessible URL for the webhook. It's definitely possible. We define what is publicly accessible and what is strictly internal with various configuration files where I work.Hopefully whoever manages the network/website infrastructure is friendly.

Comment: oh for local development, say you want to test your bot/webhook without deploying it to a server somewhere, take a look at ngrok. It allows you to run your project locally and then have a publicly accessible URL pointing to it so you can test that things work with real events. https://ngrok.com/